# newcomer here, any suggestions about developing a new smart contract

Tags: contract-design

I want to develop a new smart contract as my graduation project, any suggestions about which client to use to develop a new contract?

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!